# vue js doesn't trigger immediately

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

my HTML code:

```
<div id="app">
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>price</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr v-for="wage_definition in wage_definitions" :key="wage_definition.id">
        <td>{{ wage_definition.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ wage_definition.definition_title }}</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="amount" @change="valueChanged(wage_definition)"
                   v-model.lazy="wage_definition.amount">
            <button v-if="wage_definition.changed" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"
                    @click="update(wage_definition)">save change
            </button>
            <span v-if="wage_definition.updated" class="label label-success">updated</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and my js code is:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        wage_definitions: [{
            "id": 1,
            "definition_title": "first",
            "amount": 151,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": "2018-03-12 14:34:27"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "definition_title": "second",
            "amount": 152,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": "2018-03-12 14:34:34"
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "definition_title": "another record",
            "amount": 0,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        }, {
            "id": 4,
            "definition_title": "hello",
            "amount": 0,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        }, {
            "id": 5,
            "definition_title": "world",
            "amount": 0,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        }, {
            "id": 6,
            "definition_title": "foo bar",
            "amount": 0,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        }]
    },
    methods: {
        valueChanged: function (wage_definition) {
            wage_definition.changed = true;
            wage_definition.updated = false;
        },
        update: function (wage_definition) {
            wage_definition.changed = false;
            wage_definition.updated = true;
        }
    }
});
```

after I change input value "save change" button will be shown, but when I click on "save change" button then "updated" alert not shown immediately.
I must change another field and then "updated" alert shown.

how can I make it immediately?

here is jsfiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/5qupbc3w/1/

Comment: Uhh... why are you naming it `vue`? You do realize Vue uses that?

Comment: JavaScript is a case-sensitive language.
I think it's not important

Comment: You're not listening. Vue uses the `vue` variable...

Comment: I renamed it to app. but this problem not solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior occurs when you use properties dynamically added to objects in reactive tests. Vue only sets watchers on the original data. If you want Vue to include new object properties in the reactive checking, you need to instruct Vue to watch them using the [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) method. For example, to achieve this in your valueChanged method:

```
valueChanged: function (wage_definition) {
    Vue.set(wage_definition, "changed",true);
    Vue.set(wage_definition, "updated",false);
}
```

You don't need to modify the update method because the properties are reactive once created by the valueChanged method. You could also add "changed" and "updated" properties to the original objects with default values to achieve the same result.